# Replace multiple tab spaces into, tabular text data into CSV

Tags: bash, awk, tabular

I have a set of tabular data that for sake of readability have adjusted with one, two, three or four tab spaces. Now I want to export it to a CSV file.
so if I am right I would need to convert all of the single or multiple tab space/s into a single comma. I have tried a trick like, below to no avail!

```
awk 'NR>1{gsub("\t\t\t\t",",")}1' < test.data  > awk.xls
awk 'NR>1{gsub("\t\t\t",",")}1' < awk.xls  > awk.xls
awk 'NR>1{gsub("\t\t",",")}1'< awk.xls  > awk.xls
awk 'NR>1{gsub("\t",",")}1'< awk.xls  > awk.xls
```

how can I do that?

a glimse of the data

```
C(SiH3)2        triplet     DFT         TO          2.013503    -620.379515709604   3-1/C-SiH3-2/C-SiH3-2-t.out
CF2             singlet     CC          TO          0.000000    -237.419131945340   3-1/CF2/CF2-CC-s.out
CF2             singlet     DFT         TO          -0.000000   -237.686609290184   3-1/CF2/CF2-s.out
CF2             triplet     DFT         TO          2.005408    -237.601091999318   3-1/CF2/CF2-t.out
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close.

```
awk 'NR > 1 {gsub(/\t+/, ",")} 1' awk.xls > temp_awk.xls
mv temp_awk.xls awk.xls
```

should work.

`/\t+/` will match one or more tab.

Comment: how can i remove rest of the spaces?

Comment: it gives me an empty file when both input and output are the same file?

Comment: Yes you cannot use same file for input and output. Use `awk 'NR > 1 {gsub(/[[:blank:]]+/, ",")} 1' awk.xls > awk_temp.xls && mv awk_temp.xls awk.xls`

Comment: thanks,
I just found out if I just save as xls file I would need tabs not commas
any idea how to change multiple tabs into one?

Comment: To compress multiple tabs: `awk 'NR > 1 {gsub(/\t{2,}/, "\t")} 1' awk.xls`

Answer (score 3):

All you need is:

```
awk -F'\t+' -v OFS=',' '{$1=$1}1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` you can do almost everything but the proper tool to handle this is `tr`

```
sed 1d | tr -s '\t' ','
```

`-s` option is for squeeze-repeats